# Comparing partial objects in ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

There is an equals function in [**Ramdajs**](http://ramdajs.com) which is *totally awesome*, it will provide the following:

```
// (1) true
R.equals({ id: 3}, { id: 3})

// (2) true
R.equals({ id: 3, name: 'freddy'}, { id: 3, name: 'freddy'})

// (3) false
R.equals({ id: 3, name: 'freddy'}, { id: 3, name: 'freddy', additional: 'item'});
```

How would I go about enhancing this function, or in some other way produce a `true` result for number `3`

I would like to **ignore all the properties** of the `rValue` not present in the `lValue`, but faithfully compare the rest. I would prefer the recursive nature of `equals` remain intact - if that's possible.

I made a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0c5ckttq/1/) that shows the results above.

Comment: Does this should return `true`: `eq({foo: {bar: 'test'}}, {foo: {bar: 'test', additional: 'item'})`. So does it behaves the same for inner objects recursively?

Comment: yes, it's completely recursive - which is why it's *awesome*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Ramda.js before so if there's something wrong in my answer please be free to point out.

I learned the source code of Ramda.js

In [src/equals.js](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/equals.js), is where the function you use is defined.

```
var _curry2 = require('./internal/_curry2');
var _equals = require('./internal/_equals');

module.exports = _curry2(function equals(a, b) {
  return _equals(a, b, [], []);
});
```

So it simply put the function `equals` (internally, called `_equals`) into the "curry".

So let's check out the internal `_equals` function, it did check the length in the line [84~86](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/internal/_equals.js#L84-L86):

```
if (keysA.length !== keys(b).length) {
  return false;
}
```

Just comment these lines it will be `true` as you wish.

---

You can 1) just comment these 3 lines in the distributed version of Ramda, or 2) you can add your own `partialEquals` function to it then re-build and create your version of Ramda (which is more recommended, from my point of view). If you need any help about that, don't hesitate to discuss with me. :)

Comment: flip! I looked at the code too!
I assumed that it would take a lot more effort than just changing those few lines, but as it turns out, it works perfectly. It doesn't ignore array's with elements between matches, but I think that's actually correct. All the scenarios I have tested seem to work perfectly. So much so, I created a pull request for the changes. https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1758

Answer (score 7):

There's a constraint on `equals` in order to play nicely with the Fantasy Land spec that requires the symmetry of `equals(a, b) === equals(b, a)` to hold, so to satisfy your case we'll need to get the objects into some equivalent shape for comparison.

We can achieve this by creating a new version of the second object that has had all properties removed that don't exist in the first object.

```
const intersectObj = (a, b) => pick(keys(a), b)

// or if you prefer the point-free edition
const intersectObj_ = useWith(pick, [keys, identity])

const a = { id: 3, name: 'freddy' },
      b = { id: 3, name: 'freddy', additional: 'item'}

intersectObj(a, b) // {"id": 3, "name": "freddy"}
```

Using this, we can now compare both objects according to the properties that exist in the first object `a`.

```
const partialEq = (a, b) => equals(a, intersectObj(a, b))

// again, if you prefer it point-free
const partialEq_ = converge(equals, [identity, intersectObj])

partialEq({ id: 3, person: { name: 'freddy' } },
          { id: 3, person: { name: 'freddy' }, additional: 'item'})
//=> true

partialEq({ id: 3, person: { name: 'freddy' } },
          { id: 3, person: { age: 15 }, additional: 'item'})
//=> false
```

Comment: This is an elegant approach!

Comment: Turbo-elegant, but WARNING: It doesn't work with non-Objects nor nested structure. https://repl.it/@Tym3k/stackoverflowcoma370283101729641
Great work tho

Answer (score 4):

**Use [`whereEq`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#whereEq)**

From the docs: *"Takes a spec object and a test object; returns true if the test satisfies the spec, false otherwise."*

```
whereEq({ id: 3, name: 'freddy' }, { id: 3, name: 'freddy', additional: 'item' })
```

---

The other way around is to develop your own version. It boils down to:

```
if (is object):
  check all keys - recursive
otherwise:
  compare using `equals`
```

This is recursive point-free version that handles deep objects, arrays and non-object values.

```js
const { equals, identity, ifElse, is, mapObjIndexed, useWith, where } = R

const partialEquals = ifElse(
  is(Object),
  useWith(where, [
    mapObjIndexed(x => partialEquals(x)),
    identity,
  ]),
  equals,
)

console.log(partialEquals({ id: 3 }, { id: 3 }))
console.log(partialEquals({ id: 3, name: 'freddy' }, { id: 3, name: 'freddy' }))
console.log(partialEquals({ id: 3, name: 'freddy' }, { id: 3, name: 'freddy', additional: 'item' }))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There's an edge case: I wonder what would this do with template containing circular structure :) It's probably fine, but I didn't test it yet.

Answer (score -1):

This can also be accomplished by `whereEq`

```
R.findIndex(R.whereEq({id:3}))([{id:9}{id:8}{id:3}{id:7}])
```

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is true for the recursive cases.

Comment: You're correct, I think it's useful to have it posted here as an option, but it doesn't fulfill all the initial requirements.